# How do I delete plist file inside iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i already using plist file to store my data and it really works for both read and write data. now how do i delete my old SaveData.plist file inside my iphone device? because when i remove it from xcode and add new one with same name file (SaveData.plist) and run it in my device, my old data is still inside.

i add my SaveData.plist using this code

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SaveData.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SaveData" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
}
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an old version, the `if` statement (if the file is already there):

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
```

causes it not to be copied to the documents folder.

You could delete the file in the documents folder first:

```
if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error] == YES)
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SaveData" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
}
```

You could also think about loading the content of the old file first, so that you can migrate the saved data.

Comment: i see, but how do i replace my plist in xcode to plist in iphone device? thank you.